# How to create html checkbox instead of asp checkbox list in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, web

How can I create html checkbox list in asp.net instead of asp checkboxlist. I have mentioned the html code below

```
<ul class="check-list">
<li>
<input class="check-filter" type="checkbox">
<label class="checkbox-label">One</label>
</li>
 <li>
<input class="check-filter" type="checkbox">
<label class="checkbox-label">Two</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your question? is there any error you are getting?

Comment: what's your purpose? asp checkbox will also render to html checkbox at runtime

Comment: asp checkbox render inside table

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<ul id="ReceiverID">
<li id="lstATo1">
    <label id="ATo1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkATo1">Admin</label></li>
<li id="lstATo7">
    <label id="ATo7">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkATo7">Admin1</label></li>
<li id="lstATo3">
    <label id="ATo3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkATo3">Admin2</label></li>
<li id="lstATo9">
    <label id="ATo9">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkATo9">Admin3</label></li>
<li id="lstATo6">
    <label id="ATo6">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkATo6">Admin4</label></li>
<li id="lstATo8">
    <label id="ATo8">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkATo8">Admin5</label></li>
</ul>
```